# is it possible to sell a web site

Tags: websites, sales

There might be a situation where one of my clients won't pay for the web site that I've made. So I am wondering if it is possible to sell a web site? It is an internet shop, so there is no content that comes with it, but the source code is fully available, and it has a decent design. I've seen people trying to sell web site templates, and I've seen people who try to sell already running web sites, and there are plenty of commercial web site engines out there. But what about raw empty web sites, is there a market for them?

Comment: If they won't pay, why not take a legal route? It would probably get you more than a user-less website.

Comment: @Jetti: Sometimes for small projects, the amount it costs the pursue the client is more than the outstanding balance. :(

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - very true.

Comment: I might be interested, depending on the language and features that are available...   gfosco AT gmail

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try to sell it as a *platform*, and all it needs is a client to give it a some graphics and content. If enough clients want a similar site you could sell it again and again. You might have to work out some sort of hosting arrangement with each client but it can be done.

**BUT**... if the original client had it in the contract that this work is for them and them only, there *might* be some problems. Arguably, if they breach the contract by failing to pay then there might not be...

This *can* be done if it's done right (and I've seen it done the right and wrong ways), but really you could consult a lawyer to make sure that by selling the application you're not going to get into any trouble.

Comment: +1 for "consult a lawyer".  You really need to do that in any contract dispute when you're planning to deviate in any way from the contractual terms.

Comment: No, I won't get in any trouble if I sell it, that's 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a few people try, but unless it has a highly desirable domain name, I've never seen anyone sell one w/o a user base.

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about the domain name, he's talking about the HTML/CSS and JavaScript and all the images, I think.  He did say there is no content, which kind of implies he could sell it as a Web template.